Finding the surface element in a 3D coordinate system
Suppose we would like to find the surface element $dS$ given a 3D orthogonal coordinate system, either spherical or cylindrical coordinates. We are given the volume element $dV$.
So for cylindrical coordinates $(r, \phi, z)$ we know $dV = r dr d\phi dz$
And for spherical coordinates $(r, \phi, \theta)$ we are told $dV = r^2sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$
I would like to see if there's a way to derive the following surface elements for each system (for relevant integration), when only given the volume elements.
When doing surface integrals (and thus requiring the surface element), we keep one of the three variables constant. Does the following method work to retrieve $dS$?

Take $dV$
Remove the $dq$ for the variable $q$ which is held constant for the integral
Anywhere else where $q$ appears in $dV$, replace it with the appropriate constant $Q$

So for example:

Surface element of a sphere with radius R (using spherical coordinates): $dS = R^2 sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.
Surface integral of $f(r, \theta , \phi)$ over the surface: $\int
\int_s f(R, \theta , \phi) R^2 sin\theta d\theta d\phi$

Surface element of the "side" (not the "bases") of a cylinder of radius R (using cylindrical coordinates): $dS = R d\phi dz$
A surface integral of function $f(r, \phi, z)$ over that surface: $\int \int_s f(R, \phi, z) R d\phi dz$


Please let me know if my reasoning and  results are correct.
Also please note that I have done my research online. Found various resources that seem to point to this understanding, but as this is unintuitive for me, I'd like to be sure.

This is only correct if you're integrating over a spherical surface with radius $R$ in spherical coordinates or a cylindrical surface of base of radius $R$ in cylindrical coordinates. If not you'd have to recur to the jacobian or the norm of the cross product of the partial derivatives of the parametrized surface with respect to both variables that didn't remain constant

I'm guessing you could do this trick of yours for other orthogonal coordinate systems like toroidal coordinates for a toroidal surface with one of the parameters constant, and so on.

Your method is correct assuming you have a suitable coordinate system $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ for the surface you are trying to integrate over, where one of the coordinates remains constant over the surface.
For your examples this works because:

Over a sphere, the radius $r$ remains constant
Over the side of a cylinder the radius $r$ remains constant

But suppose we are trying to calculate a surface integral over the top or bottom of a cylinder using spherical coordinates. Then none of the coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$ remains constant. In this case we must find a parameterization of one of the coordinates, say $r$ as a function of the other two.
The general formulation for surface integrals can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields

Thanks for answering. So let me see if I understand: if A. my coordinate system is orthogonal, and B. the surface integral I'm doing involves holding one of the 3 coordinates constant, than I can use the method I outlined. Correct?

Not sure if you need an orthogonal coordinate system, but yes B must hold.
